# ASP.NET TreeNode selecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, treeview, treenode

I made a treeview in my `.aspx` page and code behind user can add `TreeNode` through the button.

The problem is, I can select only one treenode but the next one I can't click / select.

Should I handle this problem with `OnSelectedNodeChanged` handler, or when I create the tree nodes?

Below you'll see my code. I'll appreciate any suggestions!

In `.aspx`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="callPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:TreeView ID="callTreeView" runat="server" 
             OnSelectedNodeChanged="callTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged" 
             CssClass="callTreeView" 
             SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle" 
             ExpandImageUrl="Images/icon-arrow-right.png" 
             CollapseImageUrl="Images/icon-arrow-downwards.png">
            <RootNodeStyle CssClass="callTreeNode" />
            <LeafNodeStyle CssClass="callLeafNode"/>
        </asp:TreeView> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddCall" EventName="click"/>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="callTreeView" EventName="selectednodechanged"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the `.aspx.cs` code-behind file:

```
protected TreeNode GetNewCall()
{
    TreeNode newCall = new TreeNode("Call - New Call");
    TreeNode operation = new TreeNode("Opertaion:");
    TreeNode templatePath = new TreeNode("Template Path:");
    TreeNode name = new TreeNode("Name : New Call");
    TreeNode imagePath = new TreeNode("Image Path: ");

    // newCall.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
    newCall.ChildNodes.Add(operation);
    newCall.ChildNodes.Add(templatePath);
    newCall.ChildNodes.Add(name);
    newCall.ChildNodes.Add(imagePath);

    return newCall;
}

// Handle the After_Select event.
protected void BtnAddCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    callTreeView.Nodes.Add(GetNewCall());
    callPanel.Update();
}

protected void callTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    callTreeView.SelectedNode.Select();
}
```

Comment: if the Tree node having leaf then it should select both of them right ?

Comment: hey, i'm very new with ASP. I thought LeafNodeStyle is just for the Node styling. leaf node is something else than just styling..?